# Generic error when rendering an Angular component

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

I have a simple component but for some reason I am getting the following runtime error:

> An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
>
> Exception: Call to Node module failed with error: Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'Name' of undefined
> TypeError: Cannot read property 'Name' of undefined
> at CompiledTemplate.proxyViewClass.View_ProductDetailsComponent0.detectChangesInternal (/AppModule/ProductDetailsComponent/component.ngfactory.js:106:69)

Below is the view:

```
<h2>{{product.Name}}</h2>

<strong>Price: {{product.Price | currency}}</strong>

<div style="background-color:aliceblue;border:hidden;border-radius:15px;">
    <h4>Add to Cart</h4>
    <form name="myForm">
        Quantity: <input type="number" [(ngModel)]="quantity" placeholder="quantity" name="quantity"/>
        <input type="button" (click)="AddToCart()" ng-disabled="myForm.$invalid" value="Add" class="btn btn-default" />
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Have you tried `{{product?.Name}}` ?

Comment: Thanks. Why did that work?

Comment: @SamirBoulos have a look at [safe navigation operator](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html#!#safe-navigation-operator)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your `product` field inside the component is `undefined`, this is likely to happen. In order to prevent this, you can either use the safe navigation operator ( it will basically do a truthy check):

```
{{product?.Name}}
```

or do an if check in the template:

```
<div *ngIf="product">
  {{product.Name}}
</div>
```